# In drupal 7, How to override theme_pager?

Tags: theming, paging

I am using drupal 7 and zen theme. And am not able to override the theme_pager using zen_pager function in template.php. Any suggestion pls?

Answer (score 12):

Implement all/selected of the following theme functions in your template.php:

- [theme_pager()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7) - main theming function, using:

  - [theme_pager_first()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--pager.inc/function/theme_pager_first/7)
  - [theme_pager_previous()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--pager.inc/function/theme_pager_previous/7)
  - [theme_pager_next()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--pager.inc/function/theme_pager_next/7)
  - [theme_pager_last()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--pager.inc/function/theme_pager_last/7)

changing 'theme' in each of these function names to short name of your theme.

Comment: How to theme differently on different views and displays. Is there some form of theme_pager_view_dispaly?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Zen, you are probably writing a sub-theme. Inside its template.php you will have to prefix the `theme_pager` function with your sub-theme name, like `pretty_pager` if yout sub-theme is called "pretty".

Zen will clear the caches for you, but if it doesn't work, try clearing the caches manually. The [Devel Themer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module will help you check which theme function is being called.