# how to use image for next previous link in pager in drupal 7

Tags: 7, paging

I am woking on drupal 7 I want to change link text and replace them with image. How can I achieve following:

- Is there any function in template.php to do so?
- Is there any way to overridden template to pager in custom theme?

Comment: Just use CSS and hide the text. Much better for accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

In template.php

```
function THEMENAME_pager($tags = array(), $limit = 10, $element = 0, $parameters = array()) {

}
```

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7

For api please check above link you can overridden.   also check below link.

[In drupal 7, How to override theme_pager?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9825/in-drupal-7-how-to-override-theme-pager?rq=1)