# How do I remove the ellipsis button in the pager?

Tags: 7, views, paging

I have a view with video and have replaced the links to different pages with a button. However, when there are many videos, an ellipsis (...) appears floating, and I want to remove it. I have the View with full pager but I don't see how to control this to hide it. Thanks!

Comment: This question has already been answered:
[http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9825/in-drupal-7-how-to-override-theme-pager][1]


  [1]: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9825/in-drupal-7-how-to-override-theme-pager

Answer (score 0):

GO to the menu `/admin/config/user-interface/pagerer` and edit your pagerer

and in **Separators** -> **Configure separators text**. remove the (...)

Answer (score 0):

Create a theme_pager override in your theme's template.php

```
function MYTHEME_pager($variables) {
  $tags = $variables['tags'];
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $parameters = $variables['parameters'];
  $quantity = $variables['quantity'];
  global $pager_page_array, $pager_total;

  // Calculate various markers within this pager piece:
  // Middle is used to "center" pages around the current page.
  $pager_middle = ceil($quantity / 2);
  // current is the page we are currently paged to
  $pager_current = $pager_page_array[$element] + 1;
  // first is the first page listed by this pager piece (re quantity)
  $pager_first = $pager_current - $pager_middle + 1;
  // last is the last page listed by this pager piece (re quantity)
  $pager_last = $pager_current + $quantity - $pager_middle;
  // max is the maximum page number
  $pager_max = $pager_total[$element];
  // End of marker calculations.

  // Prepare for generation loop.
  $i = $pager_first;
  if ($pager_last > $pager_max) {
    // Adjust "center" if at end of query.
    $i = $i + ($pager_max - $pager_last);
    $pager_last = $pager_max;
  }
  if ($i <= 0) {
    // Adjust "center" if at start of query.
    $pager_last = $pager_last + (1 - $i);
    $i = 1;
  }
  // End of generation loop preparation.

  $li_first = theme('pager_first', array('text' => (isset($tags[0]) ? $tags[0] : t('« first')), 'element' => $element, 'parameters' => $parameters));
  $li_previous = theme('pager_previous', array('text' => (isset($tags[1]) ? $tags[1] : t('‹ previous')), 'element' => $element, 'interval' => 1, 'parameters' => $parameters));
  $li_next = theme('pager_next', array('text' => (isset($tags[3]) ? $tags[3] : t('next ›')), 'element' => $element, 'interval' => 1, 'parameters' => $parameters));
  $li_last = theme('pager_last', array('text' => (isset($tags[4]) ? $tags[4] : t('last »')), 'element' => $element, 'parameters' => $parameters));

  if ($pager_total[$element] > 1) {
    if ($li_first) {
      $items[] = array(
        'class' => array('pager-first'),
        'data' => $li_first,
      );
    }
    if ($li_previous) {
      $items[] = array(
        'class' => array('pager-previous'),
        'data' => $li_previous,
      );
    }

    // When there is more than one page, create the pager list.
    if ($i != $pager_max) {
      if ($i > 1) {
        $items[] = array(
          'class' => array('pager-ellipsis'),
          'data' => '…',
        );
      }
      // Now generate the actual pager piece.
      for (; $i <= $pager_last && $i <= $pager_max; $i++) {
        if ($i < $pager_current) {
          $items[] = array(
            'class' => array('pager-item'),
            'data' => theme('pager_previous', array('text' => $i, 'element' => $element, 'interval' => ($pager_current - $i), 'parameters' => $parameters)),
          );
        }
        if ($i == $pager_current) {
          $items[] = array(
            'class' => array('pager-current'),
            'data' => $i,
          );
        }
        if ($i > $pager_current) {
          $items[] = array(
            'class' => array('pager-item'),
            'data' => theme('pager_next', array('text' => $i, 'element' => $element, 'interval' => ($i - $pager_current), 'parameters' => $parameters)),
          );
        }
      }
      if ($i < $pager_max) {
        $items[] = array(
          'class' => array('pager-ellipsis'),
          'data' => '…',
        );
      }
    }
    // End generation.
    if ($li_next) {
      $items[] = array(
        'class' => array('pager-next'),
        'data' => $li_next,
      );
    }
    if ($li_last) {
      $items[] = array(
        'class' => array('pager-last'),
        'data' => $li_last,
      );
    }
    return '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . t('Pages') . '</h2>' . theme('item_list', array(
      'items' => $items,
      'attributes' => array('class' => array('pager')),
    ));
  }
}
```

There are two chunks you can remove:

```
if ($i > 1) {
  $items[] = array(
    'class' => array('pager-ellipsis'),
    'data' => '…',
  );
}
```

and

```
if ($i < $pager_max) {
   $items[] = array(
     'class' => array('pager-ellipsis'),
     'data' => '…',
   );
}
```